# How to move tabs below address bar Firefox 84

Tags: firefox

Firefox upgraded without my permission and now I can't get my tabs to position below the address bar.

Anyone know if a new code is needed for FF84?  This is the code I currently have in my userChrome.css

```css
/* TABS: on bottom */
#navigator-toolbox toolbar:not(#nav-bar):not(#toolbar-menubar) {-moz-box-ordinal-group:10}
#TabsToolbar {-moz-box-ordinal-group:1000!important}

#TabsToolbar {
 position: absolute !important;
 bottom: 0 !important;
 width: 100vw !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous fix for this was recently broken again in version 94 so even if you've done this before, you probably need to do it again now.  Tabs on top should be an option that we can turn off but until it is, here is a fix.

The fix involves creating/editing a userChrome.css file on your computer and adding css to it from the following sources.  It's not complicated but may be difficult if you're not comfortable navigating the file system and editing files.

This readme explains how to edit your userChrome file:

https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks

Then you will need to add this css for the tabs-on-bottom fix:

https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/tabs_on_bottom.css

And if you're on windows, you should add this css to fix the Windows window controls:

https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/tree/master/chrome/window_control_placeholder_support.css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Rather than include snippets which could quickly become out of date, I felt it better to include the links to the git repository which will always be current.